# Display JSON as table in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have the following JSON file

```
[{
"ID": 1,
"Name": "John Smith",
"IDNumber": "7606015012088"
},
{
"ID": 2,
"Name": "Molly Malone",
"IDNumber": "8606125033087"
}]
```

Which I want to display it in table format.I have parsed the json file using json.load(filename)

I have tried something like:

Views.py

```
import json

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

# Create your views here.

with open('/home/kunal.jamdade/Desktop/PyCharmProjects/demo.json') as d:
    data = json.load(d)


def load_json_table_format(request):
    print(data)
    html = render_to_string()
    return HttpResponse({'d':data}, 'demoApp/demo.html', content_type="application/html")
    #return JsonResponse(data, safe=False,content_type="application/html")
    #return render(request, 'demoApp/demo.html', {'d': data}, content_type="application/html")
```

demo.html

```
<body>
{% if data %}
<table>
    {% for k in d %}
    {% for item_1, item_2 in k.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item_1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ item_2 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
</body>
```

But it is not printing the anything?

Comment: Try to rewrite `{% if data %}` to `{% if d %}`

Answer (score 3):

The only problem I see is that you have used `{% if data %}`. Instead use `{% if d %}`. As you sent `data` as `d`.

Comment: It is giving error saying "Type Error" "__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'content_type'"

Comment: Ok, use `render(request, 'demoApp/demo.html', {'d': data}` instead of `HttpResponse`

Comment: thanks. I did the same way. Instead of content_type="application/html" is used content_type="text/html".

Answer (score 2):

## pip install json2html # Use this Library

## In Views.py

from json2html import *

def read_data(request):
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
input_data = json.load(f)

```
done = json2html.convert(json=input_data)
with open(".//templates//dataview.html",'w') as f:
    f.writelines(done)

return render(request, 'dataview.html')
```

## This is working fine